# Handling type erasure of nested Observable in groupBy

Tags: scala, rx-java

Consider this (contrived) code :

```scala
sealed abstract class MyCaseClass(val num : Long)
case class CaseOne(override val num : Long) extends MyCaseClass(num)
case class CaseTwo(override val num : Long) extends MyCaseClass(num)

val groupedObs : Observable[(Long, Observable[MyCaseClass])] =
    Observable(1 to 20) map {
      x => if (x > 10) CaseOne(x) else CaseTwo(x)
  } groupBy {
    case CaseOne(x) => x % 2 == 0
    case CaseTwo(x) => x % 2 == 0
  }

groupedObs subscribe ( (onNext : (Long,Observable[MyCaseClass])) => onNext match {
        case (even : Boolean, o : Observable[CaseOne] ) => println("Case one")
        case (even : Boolean, o : Observable[CaseTwo] ) => println("Case two")
    }
)
```

It creates an observable, where the first 10 are `CaseOne` and the next are `CaseTwo`. It then groups them by whether they are even or odd. So, the grouped observable ends up being of type `Observable[(Long, Observable[MyCaseClass])]`, as per the RX-Java spec.

However, when we come to subscribe to a 'groupedby' observable, type erasure means the signature of the nested Observable is lost i.e. we can't tell whether it is CaseOne or CaseTwo (it becomes of type `Any`) - the compiler warns about this, and so the output is

```
Case one
Case one
Case one
...
```

**My question is, in the above scenario, how do you handle the type erasure of the nested Observable?**

My only workaround so far has been to include an extra value in the key which is used to identify the nested Observable type, and then to cast (using `asInstance`) to this type. But this isn't very nice.

Also note, although I don't use `even` in this example, it directly reflects the structure of my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that all observables contained in the result of `groupedObs` are `Observable[MyCaseClass]` *and not* `Observable[CaseOne]` or `Observable[CaseTwo]`. So if there was no erasure and the type check *did* work you would get `MatchError` instead. In fact, in your case observables under each key will include both `CaseOne` and `CaseTwo` elements.

So yes, you need to include the extra data. You have two options.

1) Make the classes part of the key:

```
val groupedObs : Observable[((Boolean, Class[_]), Observable[MyCaseClass])] =
    Observable(1 to 20) map {
      x => if (x > 10) CaseOne(x) else CaseTwo(x)
  } groupBy {
    case CaseOne(x) => (x % 2 == 0, classOf[CaseOne])
    case CaseTwo(x) => (x % 2 == 0, classOf[CaseTwo])
  }

groupedObs subscribe ( (onNext : ((Boolean, Class[_]), Observable[MyCaseClass])) => onNext match {
        case ((even : Boolean, c: Class[_]), o : Observable[_]) if c == classOf[CaseOne] => println("Case one")
        case ((even : Boolean, c: Class[_]), o : Observable[_]) if c == classOf[CaseTwo] => println("Case two")
    }
)
```

2) Check the elements of the nested observable:

```
// groupedObs as in your code, not as above
groupedObs subscribe {
  case (even : Boolean, o : Observable[MyCaseClass] ) => 
    o subscribe { 
      case _: CaseOne => println("Case one")
      case _: CaseTwo => println("Case two")
    }
}
```

This prints output for every element of the original observable; alternately, you can stop after the first element (e.g. because you know all elements for the same key have the same class), etc.

Comment: Come back to this after a long time. I think your answer is correct, but I can't figure out how you would match against `Class[T]` or `ClassTag[T]` to determine the type of the `Observable` in the `case` expression inside the subscription? Could you give a practical example of both the `groupBy` and corresponding `subscribe` invocation?